# Replace user shell from dash to bash

Tags: bash, debian, tty, dash

Everytime I use my terminal, I am always put into the dash shell instead of bash. Is there any way to change this even just for my user only? Tried apt-alternatives but setting the default shell can't be found.

I am using Debian Jessie testing btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not Debian user, but all installed shells you can check in:

```
/etc/shells
```

to change shell, you can use

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

to check active shell use

```
echo $SHELL
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

You can also edit `/etc/password` and modify your line with `/bin/bash` @ the end of the line